# Using an environment such as itemize in a tikz node shifts vertical alignment

Tags: latex, alignment, beamer, tikz

If I use an environment in a tikz node, the vertical alignment is shifted. The following example shows the difference, in the first case, where no environment is used, everything is fine.

```
\begin{frame}

% alignment is correct without using itemize
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text width=\textwidth, text centered,fill=yellow, fill opacity=0.4,text opacity=1, rounded corners, inner sep= 0em, outer sep=0em]{test};
\end{tikzpicture}

% alignment is shifted vertically
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text width=\textwidth, text centered,fill=yellow, fill opacity=0.4,text opacity=1, rounded corners, inner sep= 0em, outer sep=0em]{\begin{itemize}
\item test
\end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can workaround the problem like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}

% alignment is correct without using itemize
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text width=\textwidth, text centered,fill=red, fill opacity=0.4,text opacity=1, rounded corners, inner sep= 0em, outer sep=0em]{test};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

% alignment is shifted vertically
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\node[text width=\textwidth, text centered,fill=red, fill opacity=0.4,text opacity=1, rounded corners, inner sep= 0em, outer sep=0em]{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\begin{itemize}
\item test
\end{itemize}\end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]